# Is there any solution for adding social profiles to an existing user with my own backend?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I want to get photos from the users' social profiles when they connect their social account to my Django website, but I don't want to allow them to login in with their social profiles. I only want to allows my users to connect their existing accounts to their social profiles.

I tried using `social-auth-app-django`, but it only allows users to log in with their social profiles.

Comment: It's not really clear what you want. Basically you want to connect with your app to Google or Twitter on behalf of the user in order to get the profile info? This is basically what the provider's OAuth SDK's are there for (also to access other features, like post on their Twitter stream or upload files into Google Drive)

Comment: Yeah, but I could not find any solution to only connect to social profiles not log in

Comment: What do you mean with "not log in". Your app basically logs in into those services with very limited permissions (AKA "connect"), even if it is just to get the remote profile info.

Comment: @MiGle don't you think you need a stripped version of the lib?

Comment: Them logging into your backend via this social profile (ie Firebase Auth) is a different thing.

Comment: @DanielF look I have my own backend for logging in, I want to make my users available to add their social profiles to their existing account

Comment: @MiGle did you try using the pipeline https://python-social-auth-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/django.html#personalized-configuration

Comment: @sonus21 Yes, as I described above, it doesn't allow connect function

Comment: "only connect to social profiles not log in" what's the difference here?